# How to add and delete contact based on user in android

Tags: java, android

I am building an app where user can select participants from the contact and also he can remove participants later if he wishes not to invite him.

Right now am able to open contact list with the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
```

I am thinking to store the mobile number in an array,but how the user will know which contact he has selected from the above code.

I am confused on how to proceed.

Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just starting the activity with an intent, you'll want to start the activity for a result. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) - the first example is even picking a contact.